# BeautifulSoup scrape from javascript (encoded) variable

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a page and cannot get a certain field because it is stored in a javascript variable.

My question is, how can I scrape the following code, decode it, and save the `<li>` tag(s) content? Using BeautifulSoup and anything else python.

Here is the code inside the `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var html_audition_details_sidebar = '    \u003Cdiv id\u003D\u0022apply_wrapper\u0022\u003E        \u003Cdiv class\u003D\u0022header\u0022\u003E            \u003Cp\u003EAudition Information\u003C/p\u003E        \u003C/div\u003E        \u003Cdiv class\u003D\u0022text  \u0022\u003E            \u003Cdiv class\u003D\u0022roleContainer \u0022 style\u003D\u0022color: #999\u003B font\u002Dsize: 14px\u003B\u0022\u003E                \u003Cp\u003EOnly official members can see audition information for this job\u003C/p\u003E            \u003C/div\u003E        \u003C/div\u003E        \u003Cdiv class\u003D\u0022applyButton\u0022\u003E            \u003Cp\u003E\u003Ca class\u003D\u0022applyLink\u0022                                        href\u003D\u0022/accounts/login/apply/41680/\u0022\u003ESubscribe Now                  \u003C/a\u003E\u003C/p\u003E        \u003C/div\u003E    \u003C/div\u003E';
    var html_additional_requirements = '';
    var html_role_listing = '\u003Cdiv class\u003D\u0022text callListing loggedout \u0022\u003E    \u003Cp class\u003D\u0022title\u0022\u003E\u003Ca name\u003D\u0022roles\u0022\u003E\u003C/a\u003ESeeking Talent \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022optional\u0022\u003ESelect a role below for more information and submission instructions.\u003C/span\u003E\u003C/p\u003E    \u003Cdiv class\u003D\u0022castingRoles\u0022\u003E        \u003Cul\u003E                                \u003Cli \u003E                \u003Ca href\u003D\u0022/casting/untitled\u002Dcomedy\u002Dshort\u002D41680/martinique\u002D159296/\u0022\u003E                    Martinique  (Lead):                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022roletag\u0022\u003E                    Female, 18\u002D25, Caucasian                \u003C/span\u003E                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022applyNow\u0022\u003E \u003C/span\u003E                \u003C/a\u003E                \u003Cp class\u003D\u0022role\u002Ddesc\u0022                   style\u003D\u0022border\u002Dbottom: none\u003B padding\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B margin\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B\u0022\u003E                    native French speaker.                \u003C/p\u003E            \u003C/li\u003E                                            \u003Cli \u003E                \u003Ca href\u003D\u0022/casting/untitled\u002Dcomedy\u002Dshort\u002D41680/justin\u002D159297/\u0022\u003E                    Justin  (Lead):                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022roletag\u0022\u003E                    Male, 20\u002D25, All Ethnicities                \u003C/span\u003E                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022applyNow\u0022\u003E \u003C/span\u003E                \u003C/a\u003E                \u003Cp class\u003D\u0022role\u002Ddesc\u0022                   style\u003D\u0022border\u002Dbottom: none\u003B padding\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B margin\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B\u0022\u003E                    comedy and improv skills, hopeless romantic.                \u003C/p\u003E            \u003C/li\u003E                                            \u003Cli \u003E                \u003Ca href\u003D\u0022/casting/untitled\u002Dcomedy\u002Dshort\u002D41680/flower\u002Dshop\u002Dsalesperson\u002D159299/\u0022\u003E                    Flower Shop Salesperson :                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022roletag\u0022\u003E                    Males \u0026amp\u003B Females, 30+, All Ethnicities                \u003C/span\u003E                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022applyNow\u0022\u003E \u003C/span\u003E                \u003C/a\u003E                \u003Cp class\u003D\u0022role\u002Ddesc\u0022                   style\u003D\u0022border\u002Dbottom: none\u003B padding\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B margin\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B\u0022\u003E                    impatient.                \u003C/p\u003E            \u003C/li\u003E                                            \u003Cli \u003E                \u003Ca href\u003D\u0022/casting/untitled\u002Dcomedy\u002Dshort\u002D41680/models\u002D159300/\u0022\u003E                    Models  (Supporting):                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022roletag\u0022\u003E                    Female, 18\u002D35, All Ethnicities                \u003C/span\u003E                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022applyNow\u0022\u003E \u003C/span\u003E                \u003C/a\u003E                \u003Cp class\u003D\u0022role\u002Ddesc\u0022                   style\u003D\u0022border\u002Dbottom: none\u003B padding\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B margin\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B\u0022\u003E                    small roles, under five lines.                \u003C/p\u003E            \u003C/li\u003E                            \u003C/ul\u003E    \u003C/div\u003E\u003C/div\u003E';
</script>
```

It is horribly formatted, I apologize.

I need to save the urls inside of all the `li` tags only for the variable `html_role_listing`.

Example:

Turn this:

```
\u003Ca href\u003D\u0022/casting/untitled\u002Dcomedy\u002Dshort\u002D41680/martinique\u002D159296/\u0022\u003E
```

Into this:

```
/casting/untitled-comedy-short-41680/martinique-159296/
```

Thanks for your help ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a generic way, you'll need a library that parses javascript. In this example, I'll use [`slimit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit) to do that.

First, load in your data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import slimit
from slimit.parser import Parser
from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor    

a = """<script type="text/javascript">
    var html_audition_details_sidebar = '    \u003Cdiv id\u003D\u0022apply_wrapper\u0022\u003E        \u003Cdiv class\u003D\u0022header\u0022\u003E            \u003Cp\u003EAudition Information\u003C/p\u003E        \u003C/div\u003E        \u003Cdiv class\u003D\u0022text  \u0022\u003E            \u003Cdiv class\u003D\u0022roleContainer \u0022 style\u003D\u0022color: #999\u003B font\u002Dsize: 14px\u003B\u0022\u003E                \u003Cp\u003EOnly official members can see audition information for this job\u003C/p\u003E            \u003C/div\u003E        \u003C/div\u003E        \u003Cdiv class\u003D\u0022applyButton\u0022\u003E            \u003Cp\u003E\u003Ca class\u003D\u0022applyLink\u0022                                        href\u003D\u0022/accounts/login/apply/41680/\u0022\u003ESubscribe Now                  \u003C/a\u003E\u003C/p\u003E        \u003C/div\u003E    \u003C/div\u003E';
    var html_additional_requirements = '';
    var html_role_listing = '\u003Cdiv class\u003D\u0022text callListing loggedout \u0022\u003E    \u003Cp class\u003D\u0022title\u0022\u003E\u003Ca name\u003D\u0022roles\u0022\u003E\u003C/a\u003ESeeking Talent \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022optional\u0022\u003ESelect a role below for more information and submission instructions.\u003C/span\u003E\u003C/p\u003E    \u003Cdiv class\u003D\u0022castingRoles\u0022\u003E        \u003Cul\u003E                                \u003Cli \u003E                \u003Ca href\u003D\u0022/casting/untitled\u002Dcomedy\u002Dshort\u002D41680/martinique\u002D159296/\u0022\u003E                    Martinique  (Lead):                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022roletag\u0022\u003E                    Female, 18\u002D25, Caucasian                \u003C/span\u003E                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022applyNow\u0022\u003E \u003C/span\u003E                \u003C/a\u003E                \u003Cp class\u003D\u0022role\u002Ddesc\u0022                   style\u003D\u0022border\u002Dbottom: none\u003B padding\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B margin\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B\u0022\u003E                    native French speaker.                \u003C/p\u003E            \u003C/li\u003E                                            \u003Cli \u003E                \u003Ca href\u003D\u0022/casting/untitled\u002Dcomedy\u002Dshort\u002D41680/justin\u002D159297/\u0022\u003E                    Justin  (Lead):                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022roletag\u0022\u003E                    Male, 20\u002D25, All Ethnicities                \u003C/span\u003E                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022applyNow\u0022\u003E \u003C/span\u003E                \u003C/a\u003E                \u003Cp class\u003D\u0022role\u002Ddesc\u0022                   style\u003D\u0022border\u002Dbottom: none\u003B padding\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B margin\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B\u0022\u003E                    comedy and improv skills, hopeless romantic.                \u003C/p\u003E            \u003C/li\u003E                                            \u003Cli \u003E                \u003Ca href\u003D\u0022/casting/untitled\u002Dcomedy\u002Dshort\u002D41680/flower\u002Dshop\u002Dsalesperson\u002D159299/\u0022\u003E                    Flower Shop Salesperson :                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022roletag\u0022\u003E                    Males \u0026amp\u003B Females, 30+, All Ethnicities                \u003C/span\u003E                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022applyNow\u0022\u003E \u003C/span\u003E                \u003C/a\u003E                \u003Cp class\u003D\u0022role\u002Ddesc\u0022                   style\u003D\u0022border\u002Dbottom: none\u003B padding\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B margin\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B\u0022\u003E                    impatient.                \u003C/p\u003E            \u003C/li\u003E                                            \u003Cli \u003E                \u003Ca href\u003D\u0022/casting/untitled\u002Dcomedy\u002Dshort\u002D41680/models\u002D159300/\u0022\u003E                    Models  (Supporting):                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022roletag\u0022\u003E                    Female, 18\u002D35, All Ethnicities                \u003C/span\u003E                \u003Cspan class\u003D\u0022applyNow\u0022\u003E \u003C/span\u003E                \u003C/a\u003E                \u003Cp class\u003D\u0022role\u002Ddesc\u0022                   style\u003D\u0022border\u002Dbottom: none\u003B padding\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B margin\u002Dbottom: 0px\u003B\u0022\u003E                    small roles, under five lines.                \u003C/p\u003E            \u003C/li\u003E                            \u003C/ul\u003E    \u003C/div\u003E\u003C/div\u003E';
</script>"""
soup = Soup(a)
js_content = soup.findAll('script')[0].text
```

Now you can choose: parse the `js_content` with regular expressions or use a lexer (slimit in this case).

```
par = Parser()
tree = par.parse(js_content)
encoded_html = [n.value for n in nodevisitor.visit(tree) if isinstance(n, slimit.ast.String)][2]
```

Finally, you can easily decode that string, which is valid HTML:

```
decoded_html = encoded_html.decode('unicode_escape')
print(decoded_html)
```

So reparse this HTML:

```
role_listing = Soup(decoded_html)
output = [ anchor.attrs['href'] for anchor in role_listing.select('li a') ]
print('---')
print("\n".join(output))
```

The output looks like this:

```
'<div class="text callListing loggedout ">    <p class="title"><a name="roles"></a>Seeking Talent <span class="optional">Select a role below for more information and submission instructions.</span></p>    <div class="castingRoles">        <ul>                                <li >                <a href="/casting/untitled-comedy-short-41680/martinique-159296/">                    Martinique  (Lead):                <span class="roletag">                    Female, 18-25, Caucasian                </span>                <span class="applyNow"> </span>                </a>                <p class="role-desc"                   style="border-bottom: none; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">                    native French speaker.                </p>            </li>                                            <li >                <a href="/casting/untitled-comedy-short-41680/justin-159297/">                    Justin  (Lead):                <span class="roletag">                    Male, 20-25, All Ethnicities                </span>                <span class="applyNow"> </span>                </a>                <p class="role-desc"                   style="border-bottom: none; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">                    comedy and improv skills, hopeless romantic.                </p>            </li>                                            <li >                <a href="/casting/untitled-comedy-short-41680/flower-shop-salesperson-159299/">                    Flower Shop Salesperson :                <span class="roletag">                    Males &amp; Females, 30+, All Ethnicities                </span>                <span class="applyNow"> </span>                </a>                <p class="role-desc"                   style="border-bottom: none; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">                    impatient.                </p>            </li>                                            <li >                <a href="/casting/untitled-comedy-short-41680/models-159300/">                    Models  (Supporting):                <span class="roletag">                    Female, 18-35, All Ethnicities                </span>                <span class="applyNow"> </span>                </a>                <p class="role-desc"                   style="border-bottom: none; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">                    small roles, under five lines.                </p>            </li>                            </ul>    </div></div>'
---
/casting/untitled-comedy-short-41680/martinique-159296/
/casting/untitled-comedy-short-41680/justin-159297/
/casting/untitled-comedy-short-41680/flower-shop-salesperson-159299/
/casting/untitled-comedy-short-41680/models-159300/
```

Answer (score 0):

No JS parser necessary!

I'm assuming you know your `<script>` contents are going to be formatted as in your example, and that you've already scraped the contents of that tag into a variable called `script_text`.

First, we need to get the value of `html_role_listing`, which we can do with a good ol' regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> html_role_listing_match = re.search(r'var html_role_listing = \'(.+)\';$', script_text, re.MULTILINE)
>>> html_role_listing = html_role_listing_match.group(1)
```

Then, we take advantage of the fact that the `\u003C` and similar escape sequences are also valid in Python Unicode strings (just as they're valid in JS strings), and parse them using the safer version of `eval`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> roles_html = ast.literal_eval("u'%s'" % html_role_listing)
```

Just to prove it to yourself, you can check the first few characters of this and see that they've been properly parsed:

```
>>> print roles_html[:10]
<div class
```

Now, you have an HTML string you can parse with BeautifulSoup:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(roles_html)
```

And grab those links' `href` attributes.

```
>>> links = soup.select('li a')
>>> for link in links:
...     print link.attrs['href']
... 
/casting/untitled-comedy-short-41680/martinique-159296/
/casting/untitled-comedy-short-41680/justin-159297/
/casting/untitled-comedy-short-41680/flower-shop-salesperson-159299/
/casting/untitled-comedy-short-41680/models-159300/
```