# Convert unicode into ascii to print html via python

Tags: python, html, unicode

I am using urllib2 to read ajax part of a website. However, the response I get is in unicode:

`\u003C\/div\u003E  \n  \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-field views-field-field-neighborhood\u0022\u003E        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022field-content\u0022\u003ELocation: North Pole\u003C\/div\u003E  \u003C\/div\u003E  \n  \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-field views-field-field-cost\u0022\u003E`

Is there a way I can decode it to print it like

`<div>
 <div class=...`

Comment: Another similar question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170753/beautifulsoup-scrape-from-javascript-encoded-variable

Comment: Use python 3. It solves all your unicode issues.